# Is it possible to calculate the standard error of beta0 and beta1 with only their Estimates and Confidence Intervals in R?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

How do you calculate the standard error of beta0 and beta1 using only their Estimates and Confidence Intervals and the qt function in R?

Example:

```
         Est      L      U
beta0 -5.430 -5.710 -5.160
beta1  0.132  0.127  0.136
```

summary:

```
         Est  t value   Pr(>|t|)    
beta0 -5.432  -29.94   <2e-16 ***
beta1  0.131   44.66   <2e-16 ***
```

I've calculated my quantile q-value using the qt function as follows:

```
conf <- .87 # size of confidence interval
qval <- -qt(p = (1-conf)/2, df = n-2) # inverse-cdf of a t(n-2)
qval <- qt(p = (1-conf)/2, df = n-2, lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Comment: beta / se = t-value.  So the se is just beta / t-value.

Comment: Your example does not display any confidence intervals, so how does it illustrate your question?

Comment: @whuber I've now added the values for the confidence interval which is 87%

Comment: @Parseltongue How would I calculate it using only the values of Estimate and lower (L) and upper (U) confidence intervals, in the first code output?